# R ggplot how to get overlapping bubble into the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I've noticed the NYT and Economist often have these cool bubble legends, but have had a hard time producing the same in R.
Anyone know how to do this in ggplot2?

[image: overlapping circular bubbles for legend]

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Create a concentric circle legend for a ggplot bubble chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612867/create-a-concentric-circle-legend-for-a-ggplot-bubble-chart)

Comment: Hi, this does answer my question, but I'm wondering if there's an easier solution? I've tried using the solution from that stack exchange question to no avail on a log-log plot. manually modifying the x and y coordinates based on pixel estimates of the radius is turning out to be a harder exercise than I anticipated.

Comment: Hm. I see. One option how I would approach this issue would be via the `patchwork` package. Make the legend as a separate plot and add it to your main plot using `patchwork::inset_element`. If you need more help then I would suggest to ask a new question including a MRE.