# Adding a customized legend to a R raster spplot map

Tags: r, legend, raster, cartography

I would like to ask you for a few advices on a R cartography with Raster / spplot I am currently working on. I am a novice so I apologize in advance should the methods I used to be not at all optimal!

***=> So:***
I have a raster object and almost got what I wanted, but I have troubles with the legend and the result looks kind of childish. I'd like to get something a bit more "professional".
I'd like to 1) improve the overall aesthetics and 2) add legends on my plot such as this concentric bubble size legend proposed in this other post:  [create a concentric circle legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612867/create-a-concentric-circle-legend-for-a-ggplot-bubble-chart).

Here is what I have right now: [death rate and exposure in France](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8miqJ.png)

What I think might improve the map:

- 1. Use a concentric circles bubble legend for hospital volume and put it on the top right corner
- 2. Add transparency to my points. Here I have 13 bubbles, but the real map has about 600 with many overlapping (especially in Paris area).
- 3. Add a legend to my colour gradient
- 4. If you have any tips / comments do not hesitate! I'm a beginner but eager to learn :)

I've enclosed a simplified full code (13 hospitals instead of 600, data completely edited, variable names changed... So no need to interprete!). I've edited it so that you can just copy / paste easily.

```
####################################################################
####################################################################
# 1) DATA PREPARATION


# Packages
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(latticeExtra)
library(sf)

# Mortality dataset
french_regions=c("IDF", "NE", "NO", "SE", "SO")
death_rates_reg=c(0.032,0.014,0.019,0.018,0.021)
region_mortality=data.frame(french_regions,death_rates_reg)

# Hospital dataset
hospital_id=1:13
expo=c(0.11,0.20,0.17,0.25,0.18,0.05,0.07,0.25,0.40,0.70,0.45,0.14,0.80)
volume=sample(1:200, 13, replace=TRUE)
lat=c(44.8236,48.8197,45.7599,45.2785,48.9183,50.61,43.6356,47.9877,48.8303,48.8302,48.8991,43.2915,48.7232)
long=c(-0.57979,7.78697,4.79666,6.3421,2.52365,3.03763,3.8914,-4.095,2.34038,2.31117,2.33083,5.56335,2.45025)
french_hospitals=data.frame(hospital_id,expo,volume,lat,long)

# French regions map object - merge of departments according to phone codes
formes <- getData(name="GADM", country="FRA", level=2)
formes$NAME_3=0 # NAME_3 = new mega-regions IDF, NE, NO, SE, SO

formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_1=="Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes"]="SE"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_1=="Bourgogne-Franche-Comté"]="NE"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_1=="Bretagne"]="NO"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_1=="Centre-Val de Loire"]="NO"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_1=="Corse"]="SE"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_1=="Grand Est"]="NE"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_1=="Hauts-de-France"]="NE"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_1=="Île-de-France"]="IDF"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_1=="Normandie"]="NO"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_1=="Nouvelle-Aquitaine"]="SO"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_1=="Occitanie"]="SO"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_1=="Pays de la Loire"]="NO"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_1=="Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur"]="SE"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_2=="Aude"]="SE"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_2=="Gard"]="SE"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_2=="Hérault"]="SE"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_2=="Lozère"]="SE"
formes$NAME_3[formes$NAME_2=="Pyrénées-Orientales"]="SE"
groups = aggregate(formes, by = "NAME_3")

# Colour palettes
couleurs_death=colorRampPalette(c('gray100','gray50'))
couleurs_expo=colorRampPalette(c('green','gold','red','darkred'))

# Hospitals bubble sizes and colours

my_colours=couleurs_expo(401)
french_hospitals$bubble_color="Initialisation"
french_hospitals$indice=round(french_hospitals$expo*400,digits=0)+1
french_hospitals$bubble_size=french_hospitals$volume*(1.5/50)

for(i in 1:length(french_hospitals$bubble_color)){
  french_hospitals$bubble_color[i]=my_colours[french_hospitals$indice[i]]
  
}


####################################################################
####################################################################
# 2) MAP

# Assignation of death rates to regions
idx <- match(groups$NAME_3, region_mortality$french_regions)
concordance <- region_mortality[idx, "death_rates_reg"]
groups$outcome_char <- concordance

# First map: region colours = death rates
graphA=spplot(groups, "outcome_char", col.regions=couleurs_death(500),
              par.settings = list(fontsize = list(text = 12)),
              main=list(label=" ",cex=1),colorkey = list(space = "bottom", height = 0.85))

# Second map: hospital bubbles = exposure
GraphB=graphA + layer(panel.points(french_hospitals[,c(5,4)],col=french_hospitals$bubble_color,pch=20, cex=french_hospitals$bubble_size))


# Addition of the legend

Bubble_location=matrix(data=c(-4.0,-2.0,0.0,-4.0,-2.0,0.0,42.3,42.3,42.3,41.55,41.55,41.55),nrow=6,ncol=2)
GraphC1=GraphB + layer(panel.points(Bubble_location, col=c(my_colours[5],my_colours[125],my_colours[245],"black","black","black"), pch=19,cex=c(2.5,2.5,2.5,5.0,2.0,1.0)))
Bubble_location2=matrix(data=c(-3.4,-1.27,0.55, -3.65, -3.3 , -3.4,-1.52,0.48,42.31,42.31,42.31,42.55,41.9, 41.56,41.56,41.56),nrow=8,ncol=2)
GraphC2=GraphC1+layer(panel.text(Bubble_location2, label=c("0%","30%","60%", "Exposure:", "Hospital volume:", "125","50","25"), col="black", cex=1.0))

# Final map
GraphC2
```

Thank you in advance for your help! (I know this is a lot, do not feel forced to dive in the code)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty, but I think this can get you started baring a more complete answer from someone else. I'd suggest using ggplot instead of spplot. The only thing you *need* to do is convert your sp object to sf to integrate with ggplot. The bubble plot needs a lot of guess and check, so I'll leave that up to you...

Map layout design is still better in GIS software, in my opinion.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# Convert sp to sf
groups_sf <- st_as_sf(groups)
# Make reference dataframe for concentric bubble legend
bubble_legend <- data.frame(x = c(8.5, 8.5, 8.5), y = c(50, 50, 50), size = c(3, 6, 9))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = groups_sf) +
  geom_point(data = french_hospitals, aes(x = long, y = lat, color = indice, size = bubble_size), alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_point(data = bubble_legend, aes(x = x, y = y + size/50), size = bubble_legend$size, shape = 21, color = "black", fill = NA) +
  geom_text(data = bubble_legend, aes(x = x + 0.5, y = y + size/50, label = size), size = 3) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +
  guides(size="none")
```

[image]

Let me know what you think. I can help troubleshoot more if there are any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer Skaqqs, very appreciated. This is in my opinion a good step forward!! I tried it quickly on the real data and it already looks way better, especially with the transparency.
I can't really show more since that's sensitive data on a trendy topic and we want to keep it confidential as much as possible until article submission.

I'll move on from this good starting base and update you.

Thank you :)

Comment: Please use the bonus system (up vote or down vote) or comments give a specific feed back.